# indentation error python 1

Tags: python, indentation

i have no clue why there's an indentation area but it's realy stresssing me out

```
print "hello!"
print "I\'m Charlie and I\'m going to test the security of your password!"
print "first I\'d like to know a bit about you! What is your name? (No data is stored!!)"
name = raw_input()
print "Nice to meet you, %s!" % (name)
print "What is your date of birth?"
dob = raw_input()
print "OK! Those answers are used to help me but are forgotten when you close the window!"
print "Now %s, are you ready for your password to be tested?" % (name)
    if raw_input() = "yes"
        print "what is your password?"
    if raw_input() = "no"
        print "Suit yourself, %s!" % (name)
```

Comment: pull your if statements back by 1 tab space

Comment: you are missing a `:` at the end of your if statements

Comment: @letsc it still doesnt work... It now says syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, your indentation is off when you write your `if` statements. You need to bring them back by one tab space.

Here is an example of the working code:

```
print "hello!"
print "I\'m Charlie and I\'m going to test the security of your password!"

print "first I\'d like to know a bit about you! What is your name? (No data is stored!!)"
name = raw_input()
print "Nice to meet you, %s!" % (name)

print "What is your date of birth?"
dob = raw_input()

print "OK! Those answers are used to help me but are forgotten when you close the window!"
print "Now %s, are you ready for your password to be tested?" % (name)

# I fixed the indentation below:

if raw_input() == "yes": #<-- fixed comparison operator here and added colon
    print "what is your password?"
if raw_input() == "no": #<-- fixed comparison operator here and added colon
    print "Suit yourself, %s!" % (name)
```

Here I also changed the `=` sign to `==`. The `=` sign is what you use when you are declaring a variable, like `name = raw_input()`, which creates the variable `name` with the value of the `raw_input()`.

The `==` sign is what you use when you are comparing two things, like `raw_input() == "yes"`, which checks whether or not the `raw_input()` value is equal to `"yes"`.

Comment: thanks. This is a big help!

Comment: Or not... :P Thanks anyway!

Comment: @JoshB. Lol, I saw what happened there, nothing you can do.

Comment: My second answer was just accepted and voted up XD

Comment: won't let me tick for some reason @JoshB.

Comment: @sidneycox You need to have at least 15 reputation to up vote if that's what you mean by 'tick'.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of issues with your program, so I would strongly suggest you to go through some tutorials

```
print "hello!"
print "I\'m Charlie and I\'m going to test the security of your password!"
print "first I\'d like to know a bit about you! What is your name? (No data is stored!!)"
name = raw_input()
print "Nice to meet you, %s!" % (name)
print "What is your date of birth?"
dob = raw_input()
print "OK! Those answers are used to help me but are forgotten when you close the window!"
yes_no = raw_input("Now %s, are you ready for your password to be tested?" % (name))
if yes_no.lower() == 'yes':
    print "what is your password?"
if yes_no.lower() == "no":
    print "Suit yourself, %s!" % (name)
```

Always assign your `raw_inputs` to a variable.

Ex:
Change this `print "first I\'d like to know a bit about you! What is your name? (No data is stored!!)"`

to this:

```
name = raw_input("first I\'d like to know a bit about you! What is your name? (No data is stored!!)"
```

Secondly

When ever you are using `if`, `for`, `while` etc you have to end the statements with a `:` and any statements which you want to execute as long as your condition is held true should be indented.

Ex:

```
if yes_no == 'yes':
    print 'Ok'
print 'Ending program'
```

This way the layout of your program will be a LOT clearer to the user. Look over some tutorials and try them out

Comment: thank you I've only just started so that's probably why!

Comment: @sidneycox - if this cleared your errors, please as chosen answer to close the question

Comment: I downvoted, because your original answer was essentially "*Read some tutorials, here's working code*". It's more acceptable now, downvote retracted.

Comment: @letsc i don't get what you mean...

Comment: @sidneycox Don't worry about it, so long as you accepted (hit the green check mark) on the answer that you found the most useful. You can only do this for ***one*** answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Josh B.** and **letsc**, I have now completed the code:

```
print "hello!"
print "I\'m Charlie and I\'m going to test the security of your password!"
print "first I\'d like to know a bit about you! What is your name? (No data is stored!!)"
name = raw_input()
print "Nice to meet you, %s!" % (name)
print "What is your date of birth?"
dob = raw_input()
print "OK! Those answers are used to help me but are forgotten when you close the window!"
yes_no = raw_input("Now %s, are you ready for your password to be tested?" % (name))
if yes_no.lower() == 'yes':
    print "what is your password?"
    passw = raw_input()
    if passw == "password":
       print "really? You\'ve got to be kidding me!"
    if passw == name:
        print "Anybody who knows your name will be able to guess that!"
    if passw == dob:
        print "Anyone who knows your birthday can guess that!"
    if len(passw) < 5:
        print "That password may not be long enough, %s" % (name)
    if len(passw) > 20:
        print "Are you sure you can remeber that?"
    else:
        print "That\'s a superb password, %s!!" % (name)
if yes_no.lower() == "no":
    print "Suit yourself, %s!" % (name)
```